# Every method present inside interface is abstract but in abstract class also we can take only abstract methods then

Tags: java

Every method present inside interface is abstract but in abstract class also we can take only abstract methods then what is the need of interface concept?

Comment: Not all methods need to be `abstract` in an abstract class.

Comment: Why we took abstract methods in interface

Comment: I don't know what you're saying, but the duplicate explains everything.

Comment: Every method present inside interface is abstract but in abstract class also we can take only abstract methods then what is the need of interface concept i asking this one

Comment: Re-read my first comment, then read the duplicate. In fact you can have an abstract class without **any** abstract methods.

Comment: @Kayaman  IMHO this question  is not  a duplicate. I think the OP wonders why do we need the concept of interface if we can create an abstract class having all its methods abstract. You can find everything in the duplicate but you have to look carefully and it is not obvious as a beginner.

Comment: @C.Champagne opinion noted.

Comment: can We  replace interface concept with abstract class if we replace then what is the use interface.

Comment: Should be said in those linked question but the short answer, you can implement more than one interface but only extends one abstract class.

Comment: This has got a bit complicated since Java 8. Interface methods don't have to be abstract. You can have default methods and static methods in interfaces.